# Heroku pgbackup restore error - DATABASE_URL does not match any of your databases ! Could not resolve database DATABASE ! ! Available databases:

Tags: heroku

Kept getting

> DATABASE_URL does not match any of your databases
> !  Could not resolve database DATABASE
> !
> !  Available databases:

when I try to transfer from production to my staging

> pgbackups:capture --app myapp
>
> pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp` --app myapp-staging

Comment: Documentation is really unclear. I think I have to run heroku RUN command on the cedar stack. `heroku run pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp' --app myapp-staging`

Comment: you only need `run` for console and rake. You do not need it for pgbackups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#transfers

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --app myapp
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp` --app myapp-staging
```

The back ticks are important! Are you using the correct application name passed into --app?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to push some code to the repository first before the database becomes available. (I don't think it's created until then.)